# How can I check for key releases between keyReleased callbacks?

Tags: java, input, slick, keyboard

Slick2D's `Input` class has a `isKeyPressed()` method that returns a boolean value according to whether the specified key has been pressed.  I want to check if a key has been released in the same fashion.

I looked into adding a `KeyListener` to the input object, and overriding the `keyReleased()` method.  However, because I am currently handling input in the `update()` method of my `BasicGame`, this would fracture my code by handling input in two different places, which I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you've got **callbacks**, but you really want **state**.

Here's an adapter:

Every frame (or on callbacks), update an associative map  (`HashMap` in Java lingo) that maps from key codes to a status of whether that key *was just pressed*, *is held down* or *was just released*.

```
// In a `GameState` class

game.onTick()
    // Turn "released" keys off and "pressed" keys "held"
    for k,status of keys
        if status is "pressed"  then keys[k] = "held"
        if status is "released" then keys[k] = null
        // otherwise stay the same

game.onKeyPressed(k)
    keys[k] = "pressed"

game.onKeyReleased(k)
    keys[k] = "released"
```

Then interrogate that map from everywhere else that cares.

In Java, it'll likely be faster and more readable by refactoring all the state `String`s  to `Enum`s, but this is is the idea. Of course, implementing `getKeyReleased` is then a `HashMap`-access one-liner.

Comment: Very cool. I like this solution.