# Implement an action "while" touching event

Tags: game-mechanics, touch, gestures

I'm making a game using Xcode for iOS. This is a segment of code I have that makes the sprite jump up when the screen is tapped:

```
//tap/touch to jump (& play sound)
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event{
       [self playSound];
       jumpUp = 16;
}
```

It's pretty simple to achieve that, but how can I implement it so that the sprite just keeps going up whist you are touching the screen instead of just a single tap?

```
//Simple pseudo code:
while touchingScreen Event {
    jumpUp +=1;
}
```

Comment: [This question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/71563/how-can-i-check-for-key-releases-between-keyreleased-callbacks) seems to be the same conceptual problem, but with the technicalities in Slick2D.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use `(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;` for while the played is jumping, and `(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;` for when player stops jumping.

Another solution would be to set the player's state to "jumping" when `touchesBegan`, then during each loop of the game code preform the appropriate movement. Then when `touchesEnded` happens, switch the player's state to something else.